# Convert cents into dollar string in Ruby without use of BigDecimal

Tags: ruby, string, floating-point, bigdecimal

I want to convert from cents to dollars correctly in Ruby. I will never have to work with fractions of cents.

Is it possible to do this correctly (without floating point errors) without having to use `BigDecimal`?

E.g., cents to dollars

```
"99" => "0.99"
"324" => "3.24"
```

The following seems to work, but is it correct?

```
(cents.to_i/100.0).to_s
```

Update: I noticed the line above doesn't work if `cents` = `"10287349283923497624861294712974892742837833"`.

Comment: Depends on the precision you need. If you are ok with cent-precision, go with the money gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-line method that also simply uses string manipulation thereby completely bypassing the numeric issues:

```
cents.rjust(3, "0").insert(-3, ".")
```

Answer (score 18):

As [Micheal Kohl already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461290/ruby-convert-cents-string-into-dollar-string/7461323#7461323): Take a look to the money gem.

Example:

```
require 'money'
Money.use_i18n = false  #https://stackoverflow.com/q/31133229/676874
puts Money.new( 99, 'USD')
puts Money.new(324, 'USD')
```

---

> The following seems to work, but is it correct?
>
> ```
> (cents.to_i/100.0).to_s
> ```

On the first look, it is ok, but:

```
cents = '10'
p (cents.to_i/100.0).to_s # -> '0.1'
```

You don't have 2 digits.

Alternative:

```
p '%.2f' % (cents.to_i/100.0) # -> '0.10'
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution instead of just saying "use this gem".

Comment: @DanaWoodman, the "alternative" solution @knut provides doesn't work if `cents` = `"10287349283923497624861294712974892742837833"`. See the solution @muistooshort provides in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7463561/242933).

Answer (score 6):

You can consider using Rationals as well. However, I am not sure do they get converted to floats when sprintf-ed:

```
"%.2f" % Rational("324".to_i,100)
#=> "3.24"
"%.2f" % Rational("99".to_i,100)
#=> "0.99"
"%.2f" % Rational("80".to_i,100)
#=> "0.80"
"%.2f" % Rational("12380".to_i,100)
#=> "123.80"
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks! This solution even works if `cents` = `"10287349283923497624861294712974892742837833"` (as does [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7463561/242933)). Do you know of (or can you find) any values (for `cents`) for which this solution doesn't work?

Answer (score 6):

If they're stings already you could use string manipulation and bypass the numeric problems completely:

```
# There are, of course, all sorts of ways to do this.
def add_decimal(s)
  pfx = [ '0.00', '0.0', '0.' ]
  if(pfx[s.length])
    s = pfx[s.length] + s
  else
    s = s.dup
    s[-2, 0] = '.'
  end
  s
end

add_decimal('')      #   "0.00" 
add_decimal('1')     #   "0.01" 
add_decimal('12')    #   "0.12" 
add_decimal('123')   #   "1.23" 
add_decimal('1234')  #  "12.34" 
add_decimal('12345') # "123.45"
```

No precision issues, no floating point, no bignums, no Rational, nothing tricky, nothing clever. Some simple modifications would be needed to deal with negative values but that will be as simple as what's already there.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I wouldn't try to re-invent this specific wheel and go with the [money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money). From the docs (emphasis added):

> Features
>
> Provides a Money class which encapsulates all information about an
>   certain amount of money, such as its value and its currency.
>
> Provides a Money::Currency class which encapsulates all information about a
>   monetary unit.
>
> **Represents monetary values as integers, in cents. This
>   avoids floating point rounding errors.**
>
> Represents currency as
>   Money::Currency instances providing an high level of flexibility.
>
> Provides APIs for exchanging money from one currency to another.
>
> **Has
>   the ability to parse a money and currency strings into the
>   corresponding Money/Currency object.**

Comment: Actually money gem [uses BigDecimal](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/master/lib/money/money/arithmetic.rb) to perform divisions.

Comment: Fair enough. As I said, OP didn't tell us too much of what he intends to do, but I for one would not want to deal with all the intricacies of money when someone else has already done it.

Comment: Thanks. I think I just wanted a simple, efficient solution (ie, without having to load a library or use a gem).

Answer (score 2):

These answers are fairly old, so I wanted the next person to know there's an easier way (if you're using Rails).

```
ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_currency(111048.fdiv(100))
```

There's currency and precision options.  See Rails [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `fdiv` for this purpose. It returns the floating point result after division of two numbers

-> `price.to_i.fdiv(100)`

For example: `'123'.to_i.fdiv(100) -> 1.23`

Comment: That's cool, but I think `cents.to_i.fdiv(100)` is essentially identical to `cents.to_i / 100.0`. I guess `fdiv` might be useful if the integer you're dividing by isn't a literal. Anyway, neither of those solutions works if `cents` = `"10287349283923497624861294712974892742837833"`. See the solution @muistooshort provides in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7463561/242933).