# Can't output currency in ruby with money-gem

Tags: ruby

If I run this code:

```
require "money"

price1 = Money.new(100)
price2 = Money.new(2000)

total = price1 + price2

puts total
```

I get a `I18n::InvalidLocale` error:

```
[path to ruby]/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:284:in `enforce_available_locales!': :en is not a valid locale (I18n::InvalidLocale)
```

What can I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The money gem uses [I18n](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money#i18n). You can either add a valid locale or disable I18n:

```
require 'money'

Money.new(100).format  #=> I18n::InvalidLocale: :en is not a valid locale

Money.use_i18n = false

Money.new(100).format  #=> "$1.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require "money"

price1 = Money.new(100)
price2 = Money.new(2000)

total = price1 + price2

puts "#{total.fractional} #{total.currency}"
```

Comment: Thank you it works !!! From what I know the 2100 is in cents right ?????
How do I make it output in dollar 
eg; 21.00

Comment: @DenieallJoenethen i think, someth like: `total.to_f`. If this answer is help you, mark it.

Answer (score 0):

```
require "money"

price1 = Money.new(100)
price2 = Money.new(2000)

total = price1 + price2

puts "#{total} #{total.currency}"
```